# Checking a JTextfield is not empty

Tags: java, swing

My program creates an object from multiple textfields when a button is pressed. However, a JTextField called 'nameField' must not be empty for this to happen. If 'nameField' is empty then I want to print a message with an error telling the user that the textbox is empty. This code is in this first part of my actionPerformed function.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class FuelStationInterface extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel totalPriceLabel = new JLabel("Amount to pay = 0.00 GBP", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel totalItemsLabel = new JLabel("Items = 0", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();

    private Container contentPane;

    private double totalPrice = 0;
    private int totalItems = 0;

    private boolean breakSwitch = true;
    private PurchaseVolume volumeNumber = null;
    private PurchaseNumber unitNumber = null;
    private int number = 0;
    private int price = 0;

    private String outputText = "";
    private JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea(outputText);
    private JTextArea errorReportField = new JTextArea("");

    private JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();

    private JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Item Name");
    private JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Number of units (or Volume in L)");
    private JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price per unit (or L) in pence");

    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField numberField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField priceField = new JTextField(10);

    private JButton addVolumeButton = new JButton("Add by Volume");
    private JButton addNumberButton = new JButton("Add by number of units");

    public FuelStationInterface() {
        super("Fuel station shop");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        outputArea.setRows(30);
        JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        errorReportField.setEditable(false);
        errorReportField.setRows(3);

        addVolumeButton.addActionListener(this);
        addNumberButton.addActionListener(this);

        inputPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        inputPanel.add(nameLabel);
        inputPanel.add(nameField);
        inputPanel.add(numberLabel);
        inputPanel.add(numberField);
        inputPanel.add(priceLabel);
        inputPanel.add(priceField);
        inputPanel.add(addVolumeButton);
        inputPanel.add(addNumberButton);

        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        topPanel.add(totalPriceLabel);
        topPanel.add(totalItemsLabel);

        contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.add(topPanel);
        contentPane.add(scrollPanel);
        contentPane.add(errorReportField);
        contentPane.add(inputPanel);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        while (breakSwitch = true) {
            if (nameField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                errorReportField.setText("name error");
                break;
            }
            try {
                price = Integer.parseInt(priceField.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                errorReportField.setText("price error");
                priceField.setText("");
                break;
            }
            try {
                number = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                errorReportField.setText("number error");
                numberField.setText("");
                break;
            }
            if (e.getSource() == addVolumeButton) {
                volumeNumber = new PurchaseVolume(nameField.getText(), number, price);
                outputArea.append(volumeNumber.toString() + "\n");
                nameField.setText("");
                priceField.setText("");
                numberField.setText("");
                totalPrice += volumeNumber.getPrice() * volumeNumber.getVolume();
                totalItems += 1;
                totalPriceLabel.setText("Amount to pay = " + Double.toString(totalPrice) + " GBP");
                totalItemsLabel.setText("Items = " + Integer.toString(totalItems));
            }
            if (e.getSource() == addNumberButton) {
                unitNumber = new PurchaseNumber(nameField.getText(), number, price);
                outputArea.append(unitNumber.toString() + "\n");
                nameField.setText("");
                priceField.setText("");
                numberField.setText("");
                totalPrice += unitNumber.getPrice() * unitNumber.getNumber();
                totalItems += unitNumber.getNumber();
                totalPriceLabel.setText("Amount to pay = " + Double.toString(totalPrice) + " GBP");
                totalItemsLabel.setText("Items = " + Integer.toString(totalItems));
            }
            errorReportField.setText("");
        }
    }

}
```

After the button is pressed, the empty string error appears even if the nameField textfield had a valid string entered, why is this?

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't quite understand your issue, could you explain it in more detail please?

Comment: Because, as is, it looks like you are telling the code to empty itself after a button is pressed, and then asking why is it empty..........

Comment: Much better, thank you

Comment: I've amended the bottom part of my question, I hope it is clearer now. You're right, I was hoping to clear the textfields, only when a valid object is created. Where would be the best place to put the codes to clear the textfields?

Comment: `while (breakSwitch = true)` ... interessting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the content of the `while` loop:

```
while (breakSwitch = true) {
    if (nameField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        errorReportField.setText("name error");
        break;
    }
    // stuff omitted
    if (e.getSource() == addVolumeButton) {
        // stuff omitted
        nameField.setText("");
        // stuff omitted
    }
    if (e.getSource() == addNumberButton) {
        // stuff omitted
        nameField.setText("");
        // stuff omitted
    }
    errorReportField.setText("");
}
```

First of all: you've created a loop with an assignment instead of a boolean comparison.
And now the problem: if `e.getSource()` is either `addVolumeButton` or `addNumberButton`, then you're removing the content of `nameField`. In the next iteration of your loop you're testing if `nameField.getText().isEmpty()`, which return true *now*. You'll now get the error and exit the loop there.

How to fix the problem? I recommend to think about that loop, because I'm relatively sure, that it is unnecessary to loop there.

A version of your `actionPerformed` method without the loop could look like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (nameField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        errorReportField.setText("name error");
        return; // error occured; exit the method early
    }
    try {
        price = Integer.parseInt(priceField.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        errorReportField.setText("price error");
        priceField.setText("");
        return; // error occured; exit the method early
    }
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        errorReportField.setText("number error");
        numberField.setText("");
        return; // error occured; exit the method early
    }
    if (e.getSource() == addVolumeButton) {
        // omitted
    }
    if (e.getSource() == addNumberButton) {
        // omitted
    }
    errorReportField.setText("");
}
```

This version uses the code word `return;` to exit the current method if an error occured.

Comment: Are you sure? because, assuming the input is correct, that break tag should exit the while loop and that should solve the problem since the loop will only run once and then break and then end the method. Assuming a new inpput  is entered before the button is pressed again, everything should work just fine

Comment: Though I agree, breakSwitch is just a bad idea if you are gonna set the value there

Comment: Unfortunately using a while loop to create breaks was the only way I could think of in order to stop the creation of an object if one of the fields was incorrect

Comment: @user3371750 it's whatever, for the moment, it works and we can work with it. I'll have an answer up for you in a few minutes..

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Which `break` statement should be reached if the input is correct?

Comment: @user3371750 instead of the loop and the `break` statements, use `return;` to exit the `actionPerformed` method early. As I said, if the input is correct, you're resetting `nameField` and you're not exiting the loop. Therefore on the next iteration `nameField.getText().isEmpty()` is true and you'll receive the error message.

Comment: @Tom I stand corrected, and yes, a return would be a good idea - I misread the if statement

Comment: @Tom I was gonna put a coded answer up with breaks and what not, but it looks like you had the same idea too, I say edit your code so the OP can accept it

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper And what should be edited? A updated version of his code is already up :).

Comment: @Much better, there ya go